# Symfony2: query_builder breaks ordering of preferred_choices on EntityType field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When passing `preferred_choices` into an `EntityType` of a form in Symfony 2.8.6, in combination with `query_builder` (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder), the preferred choices are reordered according to `query_builder` :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Symfony, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5136. @Bernhard Schussek explains the reason:

> I think the problem here is that `choices` contains a sorted array and `preferred_choices` picks values out of that array, maintaining the original order.

So it's not `query_builder` that actually breaks the ordering. Apparently the `preferred_choices` are **always** in the same order as the entire choices list.

Workaround: In your FormType, add a helper column to take care of the order *within* the preferred choices:

```
$qb = function (EntityRepository $er)
{
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN a.name=\'Whatever\' then 1 ELSE 2 END) AS HIDDEN tmp') // HIDDEN is important!
        ->addOrderBy('tmp', 'ASC')->addOrderBy('a.name', 'ASC');
};
```

Then:

```
->add('field', EntityType::class, array('query_builder'=>$qb, ...)
```